# Identify Invalid Characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to loop through each letter of a word document and compare each against a list of valid characters. If the current character is not in the list, its font color should be changed.

I am a newbie to VBA and have written a small looping code but it takes very long to go through even a small word file. Code is below -

```
Sub LoopThruFile()
Dim doc As Document
Dim CurrChar As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set doc = ActiveDocument

For i = 1 To doc.Range.Characters.Count
    CurrChar = doc.Range.Characters(i)
    If InStr("01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,.-_()/@:&\%", CurrChar) = 0 Then
        doc.Range.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Is there a better and faster code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me. Try this:

```
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .text = "[!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9\,\.\-_\(\)\/\\\@\:\&\%]"
    .Replacement.text = ""
    .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Comment: Hi, this is the best and it flies. Thanks. Surprisingly, however, it does not pick some other language letters as invalid though other scripts do. What could be the reason. The valid characters string is same except that you have prefixed "\" with symbols.

Comment: Could you please let us know which characters slip through that ought to get caught?

Comment: These are some of the characters. These are in Hindi language in Devnagari Script.  -  वा लो कु मा गहा बंअँ सी भाजीटीसी बेलापुवी मुं मोबा

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce this. I don't understand it, but I can reproduce it. Unicode ranges won't work either. Go with Cindy's solution or prepare for a workaround outside of Word.

Answer (score 1):

Looping individual characters is slow. One thing that could speed performance in your example is to reduce the number of hierarchy levels working against the Range directly:

```
Dim doc as Document
Dim docRange as Range
Dim CurrChar as String

Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set docRange = doc.Content
```

Note that Document.Range is actually a method that expects two parameters; Document.Content automatically returns the entire Range as a property, so would be more correct.

Then, the Character object is actually a Range object. The VBA has to convert your line of code to include the Text property in order to assign CurrChar to a String. Probably doesn't make a lot of difference, but more correct and probably a little faster:

```
CurrChar = docRange.Characters(i).Text
```

Sometimes a loop can be faster if you run from the end of the document to the beginning:

```
For i = docRange.Characters.Count to 1 Step -1
  CurrChar = docRange.Characters(i).Text
  If InStr("01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,.-_()/@:&\%", CurrChar) = 0 Then
    docRange.Characters(i).Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
  End If
Next
```

You could also try using `For Each`, which might be the fastest in this scenario since you save multiple calls of `doc.Range.Characters(i)` each of which consumes resources.

```
Dim CurrChar as Range

For Each CurrChar in docRange.Characters
  If InStr("01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,.-_()/@:&\%", CurrChar.Text) = 0 Then
    CurrChar.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Hi Cindy. Very well explained. It is very significantly fast. However, need to add a few more characters in the valid list - especially the double quote ("). How is that put in the string? Is it \" or something else. Further, with all the three solutions, the word list numbers are not considered as numerals and are being picked as invalid. Same for bullet point such as "-". How can I declare them as valid characters.

Comment: @dhatul Well, since I use your code, these problems must have existed already and are therefore not part of the original question. By rights, you should ask a new question for this. For the quotes, use: & Chr(34) at the end of your string (following  <%").